# SWIFT 3 Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION(code=EXC_1386_INVOP,subcode=0*0)

Tags: arrays, swift, dictionary, exc-bad-instruction

```
let roupa1: [String: String] = ["ID": "H1", "Descricao": "Roupa bacana!", "Preco": "40$"]
var roupasArray = [Dictionary<String, String>()]
roupasArray.append(roupa1)

UserDefaults.standard.set(roupasArray, forKey: "Roupas")

if let objecto = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "Roupas") as? Array<Dictionary<String, String>>{
    lbtest.text = (objecto[0]["ID"])
}
```

Can someone help me? I am new at swift 3.0 and looked everywhere but can't find a solution

Comment: What happens when the array has less then 2 elements, and you try to access the second (index 1) element?

Comment: Do not post code as an image. Please [edit] your question and copy and paste actual code, as text, into your question.

Comment: With the code on the image above he makes the array where the first object is empty and the second has imformation

Comment: Which line is causing the error?

Comment: lbtest.text = (objecto[0]["ID"])

Comment: Verify your `latest` outlet is connected.

Comment: Most likely you mean `var roupasArray = [Dictionary<String, String>]()`

Comment: Thanks rmaddy. I don't know why but sometimes the Xcode deletes the connections!